# Is [tag:block] useful?

Tags: discussion, tag-burnination

I noticed that we have a [block](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/block) tag. The word by itself is ambiguous, and the tag has no description. Can that tag be turned into something useful, or should it go?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/340016/what-does-it-imply-if-debugfs-says-cant-read-next-inode-when-doing-inode-scan and http://serverfault.com/questions/481864/how-to-block-filter-responses-based-on-content-disposition-in-iis-7-5 should not appear next to each other in a tag :)

Comment: @FalconMomot Hah, great example.

Comment: Does that mean we should just remove the tag where it is used? Or are there other tags we can use instead?